# C++ hangUp after removing unused variables

Tags: c++

This simple code is introduced in Dev C++. In this code variables `f` and `a` aren't used. After I remove or comment them, the program hangs up. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define N  10*1000*1000
bool p[N];
int f[N], a[N];
vector<int> primes;


int main()
{
    for(int i=2 ; i<=N ; i++)
       if(!p[i])
       {
            for(int j=i ; j<=N ; j+=i)
                 p[j]=true;// or =1
                 primes.push_back(i);            
       }


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Care to explain what "is hangUp" means?

Comment: because  p[j]=true;// or =1 is done by the first for and the primes.push_back(i);        is part of the if, completely remove for(int j=i ; j<=N ; j+=i)
                 p[j]=true;// or =1

Comment: You don't want to do p[i] if i = N, which it will be at the end of the  outer for loop. Same goes for p[j] in the next for loop.

Comment: I'd set N to a smaller value - say 20 - then step through the code with a debugger. Perhaps the "hang up" is when you reach the pause.

Comment: @Poldie witch line program use `f` and `a` variables?

Comment: Works fine with VS2012, Dev-C++ is  outdated.

Comment: None.  Which suggests some sort of problem with undefined behaviour, and that might be because of the but in your code where you read memory outside of the size of the array p.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading/ writing after the bounds of the p array.

In the memory, after the p[N] array comes the f[N] array, then the a[N] array.

So when you are trying to write p[n] you will actually write f[0] .

When you remove the f and a array , you will write into something from vector < int > primes.

vector is a class so you screw something important . My guess is that your code will freeze when j == N , at the push_back call.

Answer (score 3):

Because you index up to, and *including* N, you need to have this:

```
#define N  (10*1000*1000)
bool p[N+1];
```

Because `p[N]` has only indexes *0...(N-1)*.

Also note the `()` added to the *#define*. Always use those, otherwise you may end up with funny results, because `N` is *not* `10000000`, `N` in you code is `10*1000*1000`.

---

With the unused variables, when you access `p` at invalid index, you are probably accessing memory of the unused variables, and nothing happens (this time, this is Undefined Behaviour, so "anything" *could* happen). But when you remove the unused variables, you actually overwrite data of the `vector` object, corrupting it, and then the "Undefined Behavior" results in crash (it could also have worse results).